# Starting Redis with docker-compose and a different config file: error - Can't chdir to '/var/lib/redis': No such file or directory

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

My `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  redis:
    container_name: my_redis
    image: redis:4.0.8-alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/data/:/data
      - ./docker/redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

When I run `docker-compose up --build`, this is the error I get:

```
 Can't chdir to '/var/lib/redis': No such file or directory
```

What is going on here? It seems the only time this works is if I don't mount the config file, but I need my own config file.

Comment: What is the content of `./docker/redis/redis.conf` ?

Comment: It contains a configuration for redis.

Comment: @hobbs So if I do `mkdir /var/lib/redis` before starting the redis server, it works. I had to copy and paste what was in here though: https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/master/4.0/alpine/Dockerfile I added `mkdir /var/lib/redis && chown redis:redis /var/lib/redis/` before the `CMD` part. Why is it trying to use this directory? Their Docker page says nothing about this...

Comment: Are you setting something up in /var/lib/redis in your custom conf file? I used the stable redis 4.0 conf [I found here](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf) and your docker-compose.yml listed above, with volumes as you have them, and redis ran for me no problem.

Comment: @bluescores I do have `/var/lib/redis` set as the `dir` in the `redis.conf.` Ugh, not sure where this came from. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the config file search for the command "dir /var/lib/redis" and comment this and try the process again.it will start to fine now...you are giving redis to actually store the db in that file...through the config file hence the problem...